# Unity 2D IEnumerator not working / processing the WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Update] here is my code that I am using. this is a in a if(Enemy != Chasing) which is in my update method.

this code is designated to have the enemy pick a set rotation of 90, 180, -90, 360 and then move in that direction for a set amount of time. then do it all over again. but when I run this all it does is

```
    private IEnumerator RomeCO() {
        int MovePick = Random.Range(1, 4);
        
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1)

        switch (MovePick)
        {
            case 1:
            // TODO 
            // turn / face 0 for up
            Rb.SetRotation(0);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            // give movement in that dirrection
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0f, 1f) * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime); // up

            break;

            case 2:
            // TODO 
            // turn / face 180 for down 
            Rb.SetRotation(180);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            // give movement in that dirrection
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0f, -1f) * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime); // down
            break;

            case 3:
            // TODO 
            // turn / face 90 for left
            Rb.SetRotation(90);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            // give movement in that dirrection
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(-1f, 0f) * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime); // left 
            
            break;

            case 4:
            // TODO 
            // turn / face -90 for right
            Rb.SetRotation(-90);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            // give movement in that dirrection
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(1f, 0f) * EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime); // right
            break;
        }


        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0.0f;

    


    }
```

Comment: Use the RectTransform for moving 2D objects (Image, Button, etc..).  `var rectTr = GetComponent<RectTransform>();`   and use the `anchoredPosition` to move.

Comment: so your saying that will work with 2d sprites as well?

Comment: ok so i tried that and it worked but the reason i was trying to use translate was so it was a smooth transition from one point to another. how might i add that same effect?

Comment: RectTransform also has a Translate function.

Comment: how can I use that? iv been trying..

Comment: It is the same method from Transform, as RectTransform inherits Transform.  [RectTransform Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html)

Comment: so i tried this but al it moves is 0.2 
RT.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: That is because the value of Time.deltaTime is very small.  From Docs: `Moves the transform in the direction and distance of translation`

Comment: ok that would make sense. but how can I solve this? I just want my my sprite to move from one loculation to another smoothly.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there pertaining to moving objects smoothly in unity.  I suggest reading/watching a tutorial in order to grasp the concepts since there are multiple ways to accomplish this.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the reason you are observing a small translation is that you multiply by time of last frame (at 60fps this is equivalent to ~0.016.

Just multiplying by Time.deltaTime does not make the parameter animate. There's various ways to make the value transition from one to another, you can start a Coroutine, you could animate it in Update when a flag is up, or when target value is different from current, or use a plugin like LeanTween / DoTween etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are doing stuff in `Start` which is called exactly **ONCE**.

You rather want to put it into `Update` which is called repeatedly every frame.

---

and then your first attempt

```
flaot RandomXmin = Random.Range(1, 2) 
transform.position = new Vector3(RandomXmin, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
```

will hard set your object to a position with `RandomXmin * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0`. Where `RandomXmin` is some float value between `1` and `2` and `Time.deltaTime` basically the time passed since the last frame. Within `Start` this an have invalid values anyway but would usually be really small. (e.g. 60 fps => 1/60 = 0.001666..)

And the second one

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 2 * Time.deltaTime);
```

is already more suitable for moving your object with a constant velocity of `2` units per second upwards .. however still you call it only once.

---

So it is up to you but you would probably do something like e.g.

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 2 * Time.deltaTime);
    // basically equals
    //transform.localPosition += Vector3.up * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

---

**Update:**

To solve your actual usecase

> I want my game object to pick a rotation like 90,180,360. And then wait for a set amount of time. Then move a random amount of distance in that direction.

I would rather use a single routine like e.g.

```
[Header("References")]
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

[Header("Settings")]
[SerializeField] private float minDistance;
[SerializeField] private float maxDistance;
[SerializeField] private float delayBeforeMove;
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RoamRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator RoamRoutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // chose random direction
        // NOTE: he upper bound of the int version of Random.Range is exclusive!
        // This will return values from 0 to 3
        // so this will be a rotation to either 0, 90, 180 or 270
        var randomAngle = Random.Range(0, 4) * 90;

        // important: since you deal with physics wait for the next physics routine
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        // set the rotation
        rigidbody.MoveRotation(randomAngle);

        // pick random move distance
        var randomDistance = Random.Range(minDistance, maxDistance);
        var targetPosition = rigidbody.position + (Vector2)(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, randomAngle) * Vector2.up * randomDistance);

        // your desired delay between setting rotation and start to move
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBeforeMove);
        // and again wait also until you are in the next physics routine
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        // then we will move the rigidbody towards the target until it matches the target position
        // (with a precision of 1e-5)
        while (rigidbody.position != targetPosition)
        {
            rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(rigidbody.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }

        // just assuming that after reaching the target position you might again want to wait for a moment 
        // before entering the next while iteration setting a new rotation
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBeforeMove);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the reason I put it in start was for testing. and i cant put it in update bc it is a coroutine. and after it waits once it never waits again. it will only run the WaitForSeconds(//) once or whatever you put in there. iv tired some things as well. but nothing really worked. I'm not too familiar with coroutines but I would like to believe I get the gist of it.

Comment: and the reason I want a coroutine is bc of a certain behavior movement I want. its where the AI thinks then turns. then waits. then move. then stop. waits. wash rinse and repeat. and with a coroutine I can use a yield return new WaitForSeconds(//) too get that behavior I want. I Just cant figure out why if i put it in update it only runs correctly once then doesn't even process the WaitForSeconds(//), it's just all random and quick movement.

Comment: Put in a loop then? `while(true){ ... yield return XY; }` ... Post a complete code into your question if you want to receive help with your specific implementation ;)

Comment: But how can I get the wait for seconds to work. As I said before I can’t put a coroutine in the update method because the wait for seconds will only run once. So too even start how can I get around that?

Comment: As said before share your complete code .. it is hard to know your actual goal currently...

Comment: so I have updated my post with my current code that I am using for my monster roaming.

Comment: No you haven't really ... what is `WaitCo`? And where and how do you run that `RomeCO` exactly? And anyway still you seem to call those `Translate` lines exactly once while you se to rather want some kind of loop

Comment: I Apologize, WaitCO was a IE as a test to see if I could get that waiting part to work. but it didn't work. I know I'm not using the IE correctly. iv tried some forms and iv done some research on them. i just really want this to work.

i run it in my update method. the if statement is just saying if we are at 0 then roam

```CS
if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, CurrentPos) <= 0) // if our current position is 0, 0
            {
                // I would put my StartCorotine(RoamCo); right here
            }
```

Comment: Ok let me ask different: What is supposed to happen? What would you like your code to do in total?

Comment: Well, I want my game object to pick a rotation like 90,180,360. And then wait for a set amount of time. Then move a random amount of distance in thst direction. It sounds simple but it’s really not… or not to me.

Comment: @TheJolt70000 updated the answer at the bottom and hope this spreads some more light

Comment: thank you so much I cant thank you enough, but... did I do something wrong? or is there something I have to do because this script is not doing anything. but don't get me wrong this has lit my computer screen and gave it light and I can see this totally working.